# Get the actual position of element in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to get the actual position of the `<p>` using XSLT.

Input:

```
<root> 
    <p>
        <pPr>
            <pStyle val="EQsolutionlist1"/>
        </pPr>
    </p>
   <p>
       <pPr>
           <pStyle val="AAA"/>
       </pPr>
   </p>
   <p>
       <pPr>
           <pStyle val="EQsolutionlist1"/>
       </pPr>
   </p>
</root>
```

Output should be:

```
<abc>
  <q>1</q>
  <q>2</q>
</abc>
```

Tried code:

```
<xsl:template match="p/pPr[pStyle[@val = 'EQsolutionlist1']]">
   <abc>
     <q>
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::root//pPr[pStyle[val = 'EQsolutionlist1']]/position()"/>
     </q>
   </abc>
  </xsl:template>
```

The Output I am getting:

```
<abc>
  <q>1 2</q>
  <q>1 2</q>
</abc>
```

This means, there are two `p[pPr[pStyle[@val = 'EQsolutionlist1']]]` in input. I want to print the position separately. As my code all positions printing in the output. How can I solve this.

I am using XSLT 2.0

Comment: the '//' operator takes ALL descendants and not your specific context element you are in. Thats why you get always every specified node as answer. You could either use the generate-id() function to use it or simple use `<xsl:value-of select='count(preceding::pPr[pStyle[val = 'EQsolutionlist1']]) + 1'/>`

Comment: The XSLT 1 and 2 approach is to use `xsl:number` with the right `count` pattern. In XSLT 3 you could also try an accumulator.

Comment: @MartinHonnen How can I use `xsl:number` with this

Comment: Well, count what you need to count, the text says `p`, the code seems to try to number `pPr[pStyle[val = 'EQsolutionlist1']]`, use `level="any"` with the nesting you have.

Comment: basically <xsl:number select="p[pPr[pStyle[@val = 'EQsolutionlist1']]]" level="any"/> means it counts every p with conditions of those children etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `xsl:number` you can do:

```
  <xsl:template match="p/pPr[pStyle[@val = 'EQsolutionlist1']]">
      <q>
          <xsl:number count="pPr[pStyle[@val = 'EQsolutionlist1']]" level="any"/>
      </q>
  </xsl:template>
```

The `abc` result element would need to be created higher up in the input tree matching as you want a single one and not one for each `pr`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
      <abc>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </abc>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p/pPr[pStyle[@val = 'EQsolutionlist1']]">
      <q>
          <xsl:number count="pPr[pStyle[@val = 'EQsolutionlist1']]" level="any"/>
      </q>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6rexjif

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, consider doing:

```
  <xsl:template match="p/pPr[pStyle[@val = 'EQsolutionlist1']]">
   <abc>
     <q>
        <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
     </q>
   </abc>
  </xsl:template>
```

However, this isn't quite right, because `position()` here gives you the position of a node in the set of nodes selected by xsl:apply-templates, not the position of the node in the set of nodes matched by this particular template rule.

So you need to change the xsl:apply-templates that triggers this template rule so that it only selects the nodes you want to be numbered: that is, move the predicate `[pStyle[@val = 'EQsolutionlist1']]` to the `xsl:apply-templates` instruction.

Remember that `position()` gives you the position of the context item in the sequence of items you are currently processing.

If you use `position()` on the right-hand side of "/", as in `A/position()`, the "/" means evaluate the expression on the right once for every item selected by the expression on the left; the "sequence of items you are currently processing" is the set of nodes selected by A, and their positions are 1, 2, 3, ... N where N is the number of nodes selected by the expression A. Which is not what you want at all.

If you use `position()` in the outermost code of a template rule, the "sequence of items you are currently processing" is the sequence selected by the `xsl:apply-templates` instruction that triggered execution of this template rule.